# My heroku script creates files, where can i access them?

Tags: heroku

My script is creating files, how can I access them?

The app is on Github auto-deploy.

Comment: You can create/use a file on /tmp ...for temporary acess....its an ephemeral file system...it will be auto deleted after request complete..for your app the structure would look like /app/....